# How would I import this in react-native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I would like to use this module in my react project: https://github.com/Talor-A/react-native-message-bar

According to the manual, I would need to do:

```
var MessageBarAlert = require('react-native-message-bar').MessageBar;
var MessageBarManager = require('react-native-messagebar').MessageBarManager;
```

My question is how to change this to a proper `import` statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { MessageBarManager, MessageBar } from 'react-native-message-bar';
```

Comment: seems like you need to alias the `MessageBar` to `MessageBarAlert` to fit to the OP's request: `import { MessageBarManager, MessageBar as MessageBarAlert } from 'react-native-message-bar';`